# Add a table row with a checkbox whose label updates with textbox input and button which deletes the row in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I've tried combining answers from a number of threads, but my very new, under-developed ASP.Net skills are not playing ball.

I'm trying to make a to-do list. The specifications are as follow:

1. On page load, there must be an input textBox with 'add task' in grey and a submit button next to it.
2. When text is added to the textBox and the submit button is clicked, a checkBox appears below for which the text is the user input from the textBox.
3. To the right of just-appeared checkBox, there should also appear a 'delete' button which will get rid of both the checkBox and the delete button itself when clicked.
4. When the checkbox is checked, its text should appear crossed out (strikethrough).
5. Upon browser refresh, all tasks should disappear.
6. (and this is the big bother for me) No database is to be used.

I'd be very grateful for some pointers, even with regards to what model to use (WF, MVC, Razor...)... Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can place the check box in a panel, and you can set OFF the viewstate of the panle. so on refresh the values will not get retain

Comment: Thanks for this Hari. Sorry I was a little slow to accept that answer!